# Is there a way to make horizontally-flying Koopa Paratroopas?

Tags: super-mario-maker

In "Super Mario Bros: The Lost Levels", there were certain winged green Koopa Troopas that would fly back and forth between a set area of a level, similar to how Red Parakoopas would fly up and down in a spot, only the Green Paratroopas were more erratic in their flight pattern.

When I try to attach a set of wings to the green koopas though, they just become standard hopping koopas, and the red koopas only float up and down.

Is there any way to make the Lost Levels style back-and-forth flying Green Paratroopas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could attach them to a track, It may not be the exact result you are looking for, but close enough maybe.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  Probably won't be exactly how I'd like them to be, but eh, it'd be close enough.

Answer (score 1):

As of Super Mario Maker v1.10 (current version as of today), there's unfortunately no way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

As of updates that are currently in Super Mario Maker, there is *no* way to get Winged Koopa's to fly left to right, the only other way you could possibly make this work is get a track, were they bounce from track to track, or just one track in general.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I've edited out your request for upvotes on this answer and a few others - we want to keep the focus on the content of the answer. If you post good quality content, the upvotes and rep will come naturally! :)

Comment: Alright, but I have a question for you, is there a way to message people on Arqade?

Comment: No, we don't have any sort of private messaging system. You're welcome to pop into chat and see if someone is there, but it's not really meant for people to have private conversations or anything like that.  :)

Comment: Ok fine, one more question then, I can't seem to figure out how to create a room, and the way it describes it on the privledges page isn't very precise